# Ember - create default record if model is empty

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple User model, with two fields: `name` and `user_id`

When the app starts, I want to check if my User model contains at least one record - if not, I want to create a default "admin" user automatically.

I have the following code in my `application` route:

```
model() {

let user = this.store.findAll('user'); // find all users

let record = user.then(function(result) { 
    let first = result.get('firstObject'); // check if we at least one user
    if (first) { // if true, then we have at least one user
      let user_id = first.get('user_id'); // get the first user's id
      // do some more stuff here
    }
    else {
      console.log("no record found"); // no user found, let's create our default user
      let user = this.store.createRecord("user", { // <-- THIS DOESNT WORK - where can I create my record?
        user_id: 1,
        name: 'admin'
      });
    }
});

}
```

This code works, except that I can't call `this.store` inside my promise function, since `this` now belongs to the function.

Would it be better to create an action, and then call that action in my `else` statement? But then, how would I trigger that action from the model itself?

Any ideas would be helpful at this point. It feels like I'm misunderstanding some fundamental law of Ember (again).

**SOLUTION**:

Annnnd it was missing an arrow.. this seems to preserve the `this` context, through some dark ECMAscript magic

```
let uniqueid = records.then(function(result) { // this returns an error (TypeError: this is undefined)
      let uniqueid = this.store.createRecord("uniqueid", {
        user_id: 1,
        name: 'admin'
      });
}
let uniqueid = records.then((result) => { // this works!
      let uniqueid = this.store.createRecord("uniqueid", {
        user_id: 1,
        name: 'admin'
      });
}
```

Thanks @sheriffderek !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this mystery is a JavaScript mystery more than an Ember one.

jsFiddle just broke... and I'm giving up on my example BUT... I think that if you just use es2015 arrow functions, they won't rebind the 'this'

```
something
  .then( (response)=> {
    // ?
  })
;
```

OR you can do a pre 2015 style `var context = this;` somewhere in the outer scope and then use that in the inner scope. Give it a try! : )

Comment: WHAT. IT WORKED. How.. what ... what is this arrow function magic?! I spent 3 hours desperately trying to get this to work and all I was missing was an arrow, hahaha

Comment: Guess I need to brush up on my es6/es2015..... Thank you ever so much, I'll update my question with the answer :)

Comment: Yeah. Ember is written in in the new syntax, so sometimes things seem 'special' to Ember - but they are not. The arrow isn't always good... be careful. Understanding how the what context you're in is more important. Look at the router for example. You wouldn't want to use an arrow function in there... young-gun: https://es6.io  ---  wise-sage: https://frontendmasters.com/courses/es6-right-parts  --- take both of those and compare.